# Why is the onNewIntent(Intent intent) method getting called twice?

Tags: java, android

I start a new activity with two parameters.

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(WebTestActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);                  
Uri uri =  Uri.parse(url);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

And catch `uri` in `onNewIntent` method.

```java
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {  //calls twice
    super.onNewIntent(intent);      
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    new AsynkTask().execute(uri);
}
```

But the `onNewIntent` method is called twice for some unknown reason which doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: what is AsynkTask().start ?

Comment: what you want simply intent .. ? parse intent..

Comment: Igor, can you tell me on what device you find this problem? I can reproduce it only on Genymotion emulator but not on any other devices (S3, S4, Galaxy Nexus running 4.0.4, Nexus 7 running 4.3)

Comment: Is this question still active?

Comment: could it have anything to do with calling the method onNewIntent from within itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WebTestActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);                  
intent.putExtra("url",url);
startActivity(intent)
```

In MainActivity;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String url = extras.getString(url);

}
```

Then, you can parse the url and use as Uri. By this way, method will not be called twice.

Answer (score 0):

onNewIntent(Intent intent)
This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent).

If it is called twice, it must have been called unintendedly: starting the activity twice? Or manually calling the method?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Navigation library you should check that an activity is not created twice. See also [Android navigation components with deep link: onNewIntent called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951850/android-navigation-components-with-deep-link-onnewintent-called-multiple-times). In my case one fragment called Back command (return to main flow after authorization), that finished the activity and created it again. After `onCreate` `onNewIntent` was called with empty intent.

Then I replaced Back command with `findNavController().popBackStack()`.