# Android navigation components with deep link: onNewIntent called multiple times

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

This time I need your help regarding the use of android navigation components with deeplink.

I have been following this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link) and the connection between fragment and deeplink is working fine.

The problem comes in regards to the activity that is receiving the deeplink. In my case, I set the android:launchMode="singleTask"

```
<activity android:name=".features.welcome.WelcomeActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
     <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/welcome_nav_graph" />
</activity>

override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    Timber.d("onNewIntent: $intent with activity: $this")
    navController.handleDeepLink(intent)
}
```

With this configuration I noticed a couple of weird behaviours:

WelcomeActivity receives onNewIntent call two times every time I click the deeplink. Having even sometimes new instances of that activity created.. like

1_ object1-onNewIntent

2_ object1-onNewIntent

3_ object2-onCreate

Here you have some logs:

> First launch
>
> onCreate: Intent { flg=0x10000000
> cmp={applicationId}/{package}.WelcomeActivity }  with activity:
> {package}.WelcomeActivity@4adbef0
>
> Open deep link
>
> onNewIntent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
> cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=https://{depp_link}…
> flg=0x10010000 cmp={applicationId}/{package}.WelcomeActivity (has
> extras) } with activity: {package}.WelcomeActivity@4adbef0
>
> onNewIntent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
> cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=https://{depp_link}...
> flg=0x1001c000 cmp={applicationId}/{package}.WelcomeActivity (has
> extras) } with activity: {package}.WelcomeActivity@4adbef0
>
> onCreate: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
> cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=https://{depp_link}...
> flg=0x1001c000 cmp={applicationId}/{package}.WelcomeActivity (has
> extras) }  with activity: {package}.WelcomeActivity@b77c6b
>
> Kill the app and open deep link
>
> onCreate: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
> cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=https://{depp_link}...
> flg=0x10018000 cmp={applicationId}/{package}.WelcomeActivity (has
> extras) }  with activity: {package}.WelcomeActivity@b78f4df
>
> onNewIntent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
> cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=https://{depp_link}...
> flg=0x1001c000 cmp={applicationId}/{package}.WelcomeActivity (has
> extras) } with activity: {package}.WelcomeActivity@b78f4df
>
> onCreate: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
> cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=https://{depp_link}...
> flg=0x1001c000 cmp={applicationId}/{package}.WelcomeActivity (has
> extras) }  with {package}.WelcomeActivity@dfe87b2

UPDATE:

1 -It seems launch mode has nothing to do with this issue. I noticed the same with default launch mode.

2- navController.navigate(intent.dataString.toUri()) seems to work fine. So I guess the problem is navController.handleDeepLink(intent).

Comment: Nice. In my case I had to set intent.data = null before calling super. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get the solution? For me also onNewIntent() keeps on invokingmultiple times when i click on the link

Comment: @Arj1411, well, I posted the solution below a long time ago :D. Keep in mind that others did the same later, so pick whatever solution fits best for you.

Comment: For me, the only difference is am using hybrid.

Comment: Did you defined your deep link in navigation xml?

Comment: @Mahdi it was a long time ago, but if I remember well, I did declare them in the navigation xml.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Testing different changes, I came to the conclusion that "navController.handleDeepLink(intent)" is causing this weird behaviour.

This is what I tried:

I removed the deepLink from the navigation, and the deep link was working just fine (I have added deepLink manually) with a normal behaviour: using singleTask, if the activity is already created, then onNewIntent is called only once. If the activity is not created, then onCreate is called.

An extra problem with this is that navController.handleDeepLink(intent) will be called automatically in onCreate (you can check that in the javadocs). When onNewIntent is called, you need to call navController.handleDeepLink(intent).

I decided to try "navigate(Uri deepLink)" from NavController and I see that is working as expected (behaviour described in the first paragraph).
Having this alternative method, I decided to make some changes:

```
class WelcomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

      private val navController by lazy { findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment) }

      private var deepLinkData: Uri? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Timber.d("onCreate: $intent  with activity: $this")
        val data = intent.data
        intent.data = null
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome)
        handleDeepLink(data)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        Timber.d("onNewIntent: $intent with activity: $this")
        setIntent(intent)
        val data = intent?.data
        handleDeepLink(data)
    }

    private fun handleDeepLink(uri: Uri?) {
        //TODO: there is an issue that will cause onNewIntent to be called twice when the activity is already present.
        if (uri != null && deepLinkData.toString() != uri.toString() && navController.graph.hasDeepLink(uri)) {
            //possible deep link for LoginFragment
            deepLinkData = uri
            navController.navigate(uri)
        }
    }

}
```

It is important to notice this block of code in onCreate:

```
val data = intent.data
intent.data = null
```

The reason for this is because if I need to prevent "navController.handleDeepLink(intent)" to be called as it will be called automatically if that information is present, causing the weird behaviour.

navController.graph.hasDeepLink(uri) will help you to see if your graph can handle that uri. If you do not use it, then "navigate(Uri deepLink)" will throw an exception.

Hope it can help you if you are running into the same problem. If you have more insights on this, feel free to leave some comments.

Comment: The workaround with removing the intent.data is super critical. I really never understood why Google went with automatically calling `NavController.handleDeepLink()` in `setContentView()`. If we need to call `handleDeepLink()` manually in `onNewIntent()` why not leave it up to us to call it in `onCreate()` as well? Would be much more flexible, especially when working with other deep linking libraries like Branch, Adjust, AppsFlyer, Firebase Dynamic Links and the likes. Maybe @ianhanniballake can shed some light on this design decision? Pretty sure they had a good reason, but I fail to see it.

Answer (score 12):

When callback on `onNewIntent` arrive for the first time, just setup the flag `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);` and pass mutated intent to `handleDeepLink(intent);`

This flag eliminated the second arrive of `onNewIntent` callback due to reattaching to existing `Activity` (with full reconstruction of backstack trace to your desired deep link destination) instead of launching new `Activity`.

Details is in the source code of `handleDeepLink` method.

Comment: This works fine. However, it's giving me weird behavior on API 19, which the fragment before the deeplink is removed as well.
`intent?.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)` solved my issue.

Comment: @veeyikpong thanks for mentioning, I added these flags and it prevents recreating fragments

Answer (score 1):

When an implicit deeplink is clicked the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is set with intent. And as per the documentation the backstack will be recreated to be in a good state. See the documentation here [Implicit deep link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit).

If you do not want this behavior and do not want to change the intent flags you can handle the deeplink yourself rather than passing it to Navigation components. So if you are using [AdvancedNavigationSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt) you need to remove `handledeeplink` and use `findNavController().navigate()` to the direction.

Also remember to set the launch mode for launcher activity as `singleTask` to receive new intents on clicking deepink or notifications.

1. Replace `NavController.handledeeplink()` in sample with

```
fun BottomNavigationView.navigateDeeplink(
    navGraphIds: List<Int>,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    containerId: Int,
    uri: Uri
) {
    navGraphIds.forEachIndexed { index, navGraphId ->
        val fragmentTag = getFragmentTag(index)

        // Find or create the Navigation host fragment
        val navHostFragment = obtainNavHostFragment(
            fragmentManager,
            fragmentTag,
            navGraphId,
            containerId
        )
        // Handle deeplink
        val canHandleDeeplink = navHostFragment.navController.graph.hasDeepLink(uri)

        if (canHandleDeeplink) {
            if (selectedItemId != navHostFragment.navController.graph.id) {
                selectedItemId = navHostFragment.navController.graph.id
            }
            navHostFragment.lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
                // Wait for fragment to restore state from backStack
                // otherwise navigate will be ignored
                // Ignoring navigate() call: FragmentManager has already saved its state
                navHostFragment.navController.navigateOnce(uri)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Store `intent.data`  in a variable and set it to null so that navigation component can not handle it. Also do the same in `onHandleNewIntent`
3. pass this deeplink to bottom navigation to handle. and if the app is already running you can directly navigate to destination using the above function.

The complete solution is implemented at this [sample](https://github.com/beetlestance/android-extensions).

Pros:

1. You can directly handle the notification clicks the same way. Create a deeplink from the actions and pass it in `intent.data` in PendingIntent.
2. You can validate and change the deeplink according to your need. like if user is not logged it go directly to login activity or else move to specified destination.

Comment: You save my day bro. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It feels weird, but it actually seems to work as intended. [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit) regarding the implicit deep links says:

> When triggering an implicit deep link, the state of the back stack depends on whether the implicit Intent was launched with the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag:
>
> If the flag is set, the task back stack is cleared and replaced with the deep link destination....
>
> If the flag is not set, you remain on the task stack of the previous app where the implicit deep link was triggered.

In your case I believe when you tap a link the intent has the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` set, so the whole new stack is created. Currently [the implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/422a6ae/navigation/navigation-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/NavController.java#632) just restarts the activity with the newly created stack to make sure the task state is consistent.

If you don't need this behavior, one possible workaround would be to clear the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` from the intent before navigation component has a chance to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue and I was following [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) where I had `BottomNavigationView` with multiple `NavHostFragment`s. So posting my fix for those who has the same case.

More specifically, `onCreate()` of my MainActivity was getting called twice when app was launched via a notification deeplink.

I had following flags set for the intent:

```
private fun getPendingIntent(data: Uri?): PendingIntent {
    val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    intent.data = data
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
}
```

And I didn't have `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the Manifest for the MainActivity, as it wasn't really helpful in my case.

I have fixed my problem first preventing `navController.handleDeepLink(intent)` to be called automatically on `onCreate()` of the MainActivity with following code (thanks to you):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val uri = intent.data
    intent.data = null
}
```

and then making the change in [this PR](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/pull/840) in the `NavigationExtensions` file which basically replaces `navController.handleDeepLink(intent)` with `navController.navigate(uri)` which was causing the Activity to be created twice as you noted in your post.

So the code to setup Navigation with `BottomNavigationView` looks as follows in the MainActivity:

```
private fun setupBottomNavigation(uri: Uri?) {
    val navGraphIds =
        listOf(
            R.navigation.all_integrations,
            R.navigation.favourites,
            R.navigation.settings
        )

    currentNavController = bottomNavView.setupWithNavController(
        navGraphIds,
        supportFragmentManager,
        R.id.navHostContainer
    )

    uri?.let {
        bottomNavView.handleDeepLinks(
            navGraphIds,
            supportFragmentManager,
            R.id.navHostContainer,
            it
        )
    }
}
```