# Android deep link ignores popUpTo

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-deep-link

Our app uses the [OpenId AppAuth](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) lib for login. The initial fragment and some info-dialogs are contained in `nav_graph_login`. After successful login, the user is forwarded to a dashboard, which is inside `nav_graph_main`, using the `app:popUpTo=@id/nav_graph_login` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` to remove the login fragments from the backstack. So, tapping the "back" button on the dashboard closes the app. Works well!

From the dashboard, the user can navigate to different "details" fragments.

However, if we deep link to one of the details fragments, the `nav_graph_login` remains in the backstack. Clicking the "back" button on the dashboard will show the login screen. This is unintended. I guess this is caused by this [from here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking):

> As with explicit deep linking, when nesting graphs, the start destination from each level of nesting—that is, the start destination from each  element in the hierarchy—is also added to the stack.

Does anyone have an idea, how to avoid this behavior on deep links?

We handle deep links in the `MainActivity`

```
class MainActivity {
  override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    // there is more logic here, but for the sake of this post, I keep it simple
    navController.handleDeepLink(intent)
  }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_login" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

nav_graph_login:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/welcomeScreenFragment">

  <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_graph_main" />

  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/welcomeScreenFragment"
        android:name="my.app.WelcomeScreenFragment"
        android:label="WelcomeScreenFragment">
    <action
            android:id="@id/action_dashboard"
            app:destination="@id/nav_graph_main"
            app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph_login"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
  </fragment>
</navigation>
```

nav_graph_main:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_main"
    app:startDestination="@id/dashboard">

  <action
        android:id="@+id/action_dashboard"
        app:destination="@id/nav_graph_main"
        app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dashboard"
        android:name="my.app.Dashboard">
    <action
      android:id="@+id/action_dashboardFragment_to_details1Fragment"
      app:destination="@id/details1" />
  </fragment>

  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/details1"
        android:name="my.app.Details1Fragment">
    <deepLink
      android:id="@+id/deepLinkToDetails1"
      app:uri="a-host.net/details/{id}" />
  </fragment>

</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951850/android-navigation-components-with-deep-link-onnewintent-called-multiple-times), `navController.handleDeepLink(intent)` is responsible for restarting the Activity. The linked thread also contains possible solutions.